# Outlook Calendar

Tags: outlook, calendar

Just upgraded a user from Office 2003 to 2007 and now a sub calendar that she had is not available in Outlook but is visible in OWA.  Any suggestions on making it available for her in Outlook?

thanks

Comment: This has a vote to send it to SuperUser but the way I see it this is very much an SF question as it relates to system administration.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding a shared calendar when first troubleshooting the problem and figured it wouldn't work because it *wasn't* a shared calendar.  Well, needless to say, that didn't work.  Also did not show up in folder list.

It seems as though it must have been a replication issue because it now is showing up after several hours.

thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

Try the Go menu and then selecting Folder List.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a shared calendar. Go to the Calendar "tab" on the left, then select Open a Shared Calendar..., then type in the name of the calendar to add it.